# Distance Matrix won't consider elevation

Tags: qgis, vector, distance, gps, distance-matrix

Using QGIS Firenze

The Data is present in following Formats:
.gpx, .kml .csv. generated by garmin GPS.

lat, lon (In Degrees) and elev (in m).

There I have 70 Points. I can create a distance matrix or other types of distances but none of them take into account the elevation. When I calculate it by hand it makes a difference of about 2 meters:

[image]

The Identify Table looks like this:
It is clearly able to read the lat and lon, transform it into UTM. (m)

[image: attribute table]

How can I make it so that all three Params are taken into consideration, though?

Comment: It probably doesn't matter to within the precision of your coordinates.

Comment: @IanTurton True, i didn't consider this since we it's only gps... 

And yet, is there an apporach within QGIS to get the proper results?